# MIDI editor application

Tags: java, swing, music

[Source](https://github.com/AlexZhou876/music-editor)

I made a project for a class, a MIDI editor written with Java 8 and Swing, and continued working on it on my own. However, I ran into a problem I couldn't solve and gave up.

I'd like feedback on high level design/architecture, things like cohesion, coupling etc between classes. I'm pretty sure the project is weak in this regard. Would MVC be appropriate here?

I'm also concerned about the model. I made it so that a composition has a list of measures, and a measure has a list of notes, but I think that was hard to work with and caused issues. Maybe a map data structure would have been better. The class for reading MIDI files became really complicated because I didn't model sequences and tracks.

The problem I couldn't solve was synchronizing the movement of the progress line and the audio playback. I know the focus of this site isn't to debug, so you don't have to comment on that.

Please feel free to offer any feedback at all also.

```
package ui;

import model.Composition;
import persistence.Reader;
import ui.players.EntirePlayer;
import ui.sound.MidiSynth;
import ui.tools.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import static ui.CompositionPanel.SEMITONE_HEIGHT;

public class GraphicalEditorApp extends JFrame {
    public static final int WIDTH = 1500;
    public static final int HEIGHT = SEMITONE_HEIGHT * 88;
    //public static final int HEIGHT = SEMITONE_HEIGHT * 70;
    //public static final String SAVE_FILE = "./data/saveFile.mid";
    public static final String SAVE_FILE = "./data/Gurenge.mid";

    private MidiSynth midiSynth;
    private EntirePlayer player;
    private Timer masterTimer;

    private CompositionPanel compositionPanel;
    private JScrollPane scroller;

    private List<Tool> tools; // is this even useful??
    private Tool activeTool;

    public GraphicalEditorApp() {
        super("Music Editor");
        initFields();
        initGraphics();
        initSound();
        showInitDialog();
        initInteraction();
    }

    public MidiSynth getMidiSynth() {
        return midiSynth;
    }

    public CompositionPanel getCompositionPanel() {
        return compositionPanel;
    }

    private void initFields() {
        activeTool = null;
        compositionPanel = new CompositionPanel(1, 4, 4, this);
        //composition.addMeasures(1, 1, 4, 4);
        tools = new ArrayList<Tool>();
    }

    // EFFECTS: allows the user to input init options, such as to load from file or create new.
    private void showInitDialog() {
        int closedOption = -1;
        int yes = 0;
        int no = 1;
        String[] options = {"Yes", "No"};
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this,
                "Would you like to load the previously saved file?",
                "Initialization",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                null,
                options,
                options[1]);
        if (n == closedOption) {
            return;
        } else if (n == yes) {
            loadProject();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    // MODIFIES: this
    // EFFECTS: changes composition to the one contained in the save file
    private void loadProject() {

        compositionPanel.setComposition(Reader.readFile(new File(SAVE_FILE)));
        compositionPanel.getComposition().addMidiSynthToAll(midiSynth);
        // important!!
        player.setComposition(compositionPanel.getComposition());

        repaint();
    }


    private void initSound() {
        midiSynth = new MidiSynth();
        midiSynth.open();
    }

    private void initGraphics() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        createTools();
        createNavigationBar();
        addComposition();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        // necessary if size of composition may change???
        setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    private void createNavigationBar() {
        //JToolBar navigationBar = new JToolBar("Navigation");
        JButton button = new JButton("Jump to");
        JTextField measureNumber = new JTextField();
        NavigationBar bar = new NavigationBar("Navigation", button, measureNumber, this);
        add(bar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);


    }

    // MODIFIES: this
    // EFFECTS: adds a composition component to the editor
    private void addComposition() {
        //add(compositionPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        compositionPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        scroller = new JScrollPane(compositionPanel);
        add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        validate();
    }

    public JScrollPane getScroller() {
        return scroller;
    }

    // MODIFIES: this
    // EFFECTS: declare and instantiate all tools
    private void createTools() {
        JPanel toolbar = new JPanel();
        toolbar.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        toolbar.setSize((new Dimension(0, 0)));
        add(toolbar, BorderLayout.EAST);

        AddNoteTool addNoteTool = new AddNoteTool(this, toolbar);
        tools.add(addNoteTool);
// should I add the others to the list?? What is the point of the list?
        AddMeasuresTool addMeasuresTool = new AddMeasuresTool(this, toolbar);

        EditNoteTool editNoteTool = new EditNoteTool(this, toolbar);

        RemoveMeasuresTool removeMeasuresTool = new RemoveMeasuresTool(this, toolbar);

        masterTimer = new Timer(0, null);
        player = new EntirePlayer(compositionPanel.getComposition(), null, null);
        PlayEntireTool playEntireTool = new PlayEntireTool(this, toolbar, player);
        player.setTool(playEntireTool);
        //player.setCompositionPanel(compositionPanel);


        SaveTool saveTool = new SaveTool(this, toolbar);

        setActiveTool(addNoteTool);
    }

    public EntirePlayer getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public Timer getMasterTimer() {
        return masterTimer;
    }

    public void setMasterTimer(Timer masterTimer) {
        this.masterTimer = masterTimer;
    }

    // MODIFIES: this
    // EFFECTS: initializes EditorMouseListener and EKL for JFrame
    private void initInteraction() {
        EditorMouseListener eml = new EditorMouseListener();
        compositionPanel.addMouseListener(eml);
        compositionPanel.addMouseMotionListener(eml);

        //EditorKeyListener ekl = new EditorKeyListener();
        //addKeyListener(ekl);
        //compositionPanel.addKeyListener(ekl);
        //compositionPanel.setFocusable(true);
        //compositionPanel.requestFocusInWindow();


    }

    // MODIFIES: this
    // EFFECTS:  sets the given tool as the activeTool
    public void setActiveTool(Tool tool) {
        if (activeTool != null) {
            activeTool.deactivate();
        }
        tool.activate();
        activeTool = tool;
    }

    // EFFECTS: if activeTool != null, then mousePressedInDrawingArea is invoked on activeTool, depends on the
    //          type of the tool which is currently activeTool
    private void handleMousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (activeTool != null) {
            activeTool.mousePressed(e);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    // EFFECTS: if activeTool != null, then mouseReleasedInDrawingArea is invoked on activeTool, depends on the
    //          type of the tool which is currently activeTool
    private void handleMouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (activeTool != null) {
            activeTool.mouseReleased(e);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    // EFFECTS: if activeTool != null, then mouseClickedInDrawingArea is invoked on activeTool, depends on the
    //          type of the tool which is currently activeTool
    private void handleMouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (activeTool != null) {
            activeTool.mouseClicked(e);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    // EFFECTS: if activeTool != null, then mouseDraggedInDrawingArea is invoked on activeTool, depends on the
    //          type of the tool which is currently activeTool
    private void handleMouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (activeTool != null) {
            activeTool.mouseDragged(e);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    // EFFECTS: if activeTool != null, then keytyped is invoked on activeTool.
    private void handleKeyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
        if (activeTool != null) {
            activeTool.keyTyped(ke);
        }
        repaint();
    }



    // from SimpleDrawingPlayer (modified)
    private class EditorMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        // EFFECTS: Forward mouse pressed event to the active tool
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            handleMousePressed(translateEvent(e));
        }

        // EFFECTS: Forward mouse released event to the active tool
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            handleMouseReleased(translateEvent(e));
        }

        // EFFECTS:Forward mouse clicked event to the active tool
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            handleMouseClicked(translateEvent(e));
        }

        // EFFECTS:Forward mouse dragged event to the active tool
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            handleMouseDragged(translateEvent(e));
        }

        // EFFECTS: translates the mouse event to current drawing's coordinate system
        private MouseEvent translateEvent(MouseEvent e) {
            return SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(e.getComponent(), e, compositionPanel);
        }
    }



}
```

```
package ui;

import model.Composition;
import model.Measure;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;

// a beat refers to a quarter beat.
public class CompositionPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, Scrollable {
    private int playLineColumn;
    private GraphicalEditorApp editor;
    private Composition composition;

    public static final int DEFAULT_BPM = 80;

    public static final int MAXIMUM_BEAT_WIDTH = 512;
    public static final int MINIMUM_BEAT_WIDTH = 1;
    public static final int ZOOM_INTERVAL = 10;

    public static int bpm;
    //public static int resolution = 4; // initial tick is a 16th note
    public static int tickWidth = 16;
    //public static int beatWidth = tickWidth * resolution; //50, then tried 64
    public static int beatWidth = 64;
    public static final int SEMITONE_HEIGHT = 10;


    public CompositionPanel(int numMeasures, int beatNum, int beatType, GraphicalEditorApp editor) {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.black);
        composition = new Composition(numMeasures, beatNum, beatType);
        this.editor = editor;
        bpm = DEFAULT_BPM;
    }

    @Override
    // MODIFIES: this
    // EFFECTS: update this every time the timer fires by incrementing playLineColumn by one screen coordinate
    // and scroll following.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        playLineColumn += 1;
        repaint();
        followPlaying();
        //if (editor.getMasterTimer().getDelay() == )
    }

    // MODIFIES: this
    // EFFECTS: stops the timer and resets the playLineColumn to 0.
    public void stopPlaying() {
        editor.getMasterTimer().stop();
        playLineColumn = 0;
        repaint();
    }

    // MODIFIES: this
    // EFFECTS: sets the value of beatWidth and makes sure invariant relationships between static variables
    // are maintained.
    // value writes even of public static variables should be done locally and in one place so the repercussions can be
    // handled in one place.
    public void setBeatWidth(int newBeatWidth) {
        float factor = (float) newBeatWidth / (float) beatWidth;
        beatWidth = newBeatWidth;
        tickWidth = Math.round(factor * tickWidth);
    }

    // EFFECTS: gets the end of the composition panel in screen x coordinate.
    // OUTDATED
    public int getEnd() {
        int totalTicks = composition.getNumTicks();
        return totalTicks * tickWidth;
        //int totalBeats = composition.getNumBeats();
        //return totalBeats * beatWidth;
    }

    // MODIFIES: this
    // EFFECTS: changes the dimensions of this. If the new width is greater than the starting width, assign
    // the new width. Otherwise do nothing.
    public void resize() {
        if (getEnd() > editor.WIDTH) {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getEnd(), editor.HEIGHT));
        }
        revalidate();
    }

    public void setBPM(int newBPM) {
        bpm = newBPM;
    }

    public Composition getComposition() {
        return composition;
    }


    // EFFECTS: sets composition to the given one, and ensures that the ratio of tickwidth to beatwidth
    // obeys the resolution of the composition.
    public void setComposition(Composition composition) {
        this.composition = composition;
        int amount = beatWidth / Composition.resolution;
        if (amount == 0) {
            amount = 1;
        }
        tickWidth = amount;
        resize();
    }




    // EFFECTS: paints grid, playing line, notes in composition.
    // calls to repaint() get here
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        drawLines(graphics);
        // it may be better for measure.draw to draw bar lines.
        for (Measure measure : composition.getListOfMeasure()) {
            measure.draw(graphics);
        }
    }

    // EFFECTS: draws semitone lines and bar lines
    private void drawLines(Graphics graphics) {
        int endX = 0;
        Color save = graphics.getColor();
        graphics.setColor(new Color(100, 100, 200));
        // 100 100 200

        List<Integer> positions = composition.getPositionsOfMeasureLines();
        for (Integer x : positions) {
            graphics.drawLine(x, 0, x, getHeight());
            endX = x;
        }

        for (int y = SEMITONE_HEIGHT; y < getHeight(); y += SEMITONE_HEIGHT) {
            graphics.drawLine(0, y, endX, y);
        }

        if (playLineColumn > 0 && playLineColumn < getWidth()) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
            graphics.drawLine(playLineColumn, 0, playLineColumn, getHeight());
        }
        graphics.setColor(save);
    }

    // MODIFIES: this
    // EFFECTS: sets value of playLineColumn
    public void setPlayLineColumn(int target) {
        playLineColumn = target;
    }

    // MODIFIES: editor
    // EFFECTS: makes the editor's scroller keep the playing line in the middle of the view.
    public void followPlaying() {
        int leftEndOfView = playLineColumn - (editor.WIDTH / 2);
        editor.getScroller().getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(leftEndOfView);
    }
}
```

```
package model;

import ui.sound.MidiSynth;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import static ui.CompositionPanel.*;
// consider splitting graphical responsibilities into new class

// represents an entire composition, which is a collection of measures. The order of measures in the list is the order
// of measures in the composition.
public class Composition  { // used to extend JPanel
    private List<Measure> listOfMeasure;
    //private int beatsPerMinute;
    private int beatNum;
    private int beatType;
    private int barWidth; // implement later
    public static int resolution = 4;
    // the resolution is the number of ticks per quarter beat.


    // REQUIRES: beatType is a power of 2
    // EFFECTS: instantiates a new composition with numMeasures measures, beatNum beats of type beatType per measure.
    public Composition(int numMeasures, int beatNum, int beatType) {
        //super();
        //setBackground(Color.black);
        this.beatNum = beatNum;
        this.beatType = beatType;
        listOfMeasure = new ArrayList<Measure>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numMeasures; i++) {
            Measure tempMeasure = new Measure(beatNum, beatType, this, i + 1);
            listOfMeasure.add(tempMeasure);
        }
    }

    public void setResolution(int resolution) {
        Composition.resolution = resolution;
    }

    // OBSOLETE
    // REQUIRES: beat > 0
    // EFFECTS: returns the measure which has the given global beat within it. If none have the given beat, return null.
    public Measure getMeasureAtBeat(int beat) {
        int beatCount = 0;
        for (Measure measure: listOfMeasure) {
            beatCount += measure.getBeatNumber();
            if (beatCount >= beat) {
                return measure;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // REQUIRES: tick > 0
    // EFFECTS: returns the measure which has the given tick within it. If none, return null.
    public Measure getMeasureAtTick(int tick) {
        int tickCount = 0;
        for (Measure m: listOfMeasure) {
            tickCount += m.getNumTicks();
            if (tickCount >= tick) {
                return m;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // EFFECTS: adds a midisynth to all notes.
    public void addMidiSynthToAll(MidiSynth midiSynth) {
        for (Measure measure : listOfMeasure) {
            measure.addMidiSynthToAll(midiSynth);
        }
    }

    // EFFECTS: returns array containing the x screen coordinates of all measure lines in the composition.
    public List<Integer> getPositionsOfMeasureLines() {
        List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        output.add(0);
        int tickCount = 0;
        for (Measure m: listOfMeasure) {
            tickCount += m.getNumTicks();
            output.add(tickCount * tickWidth);
        }
        return output;
    }


    // EFFECTS: returns the global start tick of the given measure.
    public int getGlobalStartOf(Measure measure) {
        int output = 0;
        for (Measure m: listOfMeasure) {
            if (!m.equals(measure)) {
                output += m.getNumTicks();
            } else {
                output++;
                return output;
            }
        }
        return 0; //this should throw an exception probably
    }

    // EFFECTS: returns the note at a given point in composition, if any.
    public Note getNoteAtPoint(Point point) {
        for (Measure measure : listOfMeasure) {
            for (Note note : measure.getListOfNote()) {
                if (note.contains(point)) {
                    return note;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // EFFECTS: returns list of notes at a given column in the composition.
    public List<Note> getNotesAtColumn(int x) {
        List<Note> notesAtColumn = new ArrayList<Note>();
        for (Measure m: listOfMeasure) {
            for (Note note : m.getListOfNote()) {
                if (note.containsX(x)) {
                    notesAtColumn.add(note);
                }
            }
        }
        return notesAtColumn;
    }

    // EFFECTS: returns list of notes at a given tick in the composition.
    public List<Note> getNotesAtTick(int tick) {
        List<Note> notesAtTick = new ArrayList<>();
        /*
        for (Measure m: listOfMeasure) {
            for (Note note : m.getListOfNote()) {
                if (note.containsTick(tick)) {
                    notesAtTick.add(note);
                }
            }
        }
         */

        int ticksPerMeasure = listOfMeasure.get(0).getNumTicks();
        int index = tick / ticksPerMeasure;
        Measure measure = listOfMeasure.get(index);
        for (Note note : measure.getListOfNote()) {
            if (note.containsTick(tick)) {
                notesAtTick.add(note);
            }
        }
        return notesAtTick;

    }

    // REQUIRES: pos <= number of measures, beatType is a power of 2
    // MODIFIES: this
    // EFFECTS: adds n new measures to composition after the posth measure with beatNum beats of type beatType.
    public void addMeasures(int n, int pos, int beatNum, int beatType) {
        //int prevSize = listOfMeasure.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Measure tempMeasure = new Measure(beatNum, beatType, this, pos + i + 1);
            listOfMeasure.add(pos + i, tempMeasure);
            countAndNotifyMeasures();
            assert checkMeasureNums();
            //.add adds the element at the index and shifts everything afterwards to the right by one.
        }
    }

    // EFFECTS: checks the class invariant that the measures have correct measure numbers for their order in
    // listOfMeasure
    private boolean checkMeasureNums() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Measure measure : listOfMeasure) {
            count++;
            if (count != measure.getMeasureNumber()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // REQUIRES: there is a measure at every position specified.
    // MODIFIES: this
    // EFFECTS: removes the specified measures from composition, and makes sure note positions and measure numbers
    // resulting are updated.
    public void removeMeasures(List<Integer> listOfPos) {
        // reverse list to remove last first
        Collections.sort(listOfPos); // have to sort first
        Collections.reverse(listOfPos);
        for (Integer pos : listOfPos) {
            int tickDiff = -1 * listOfMeasure.get(pos - 1).getNumTicks();
            updateNotePositions(tickDiff, pos); // pos - 1 + 1
            listOfMeasure.remove(pos - 1);
        }
        countAndNotifyMeasures();
    }

    // MODIFIES: this
    // EFFECTS: for all measures from the one after the one to be removed until the end, adjust note starts by
    // tickDiff.
    private void updateNotePositions(int tickDiff, int index) {
        for (int i = index; i < listOfMeasure.size(); i++) {
            listOfMeasure.get(i).adjustNotes(tickDiff);
        }
    }

    // EFFECTS: notifies all measures of their measure numbers.
    private void countAndNotifyMeasures() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Measure measure: listOfMeasure) {
            count++;
            measure.setMeasureNumber(count);
        }
    }

    // EFFECTS: returns the number of measures in the composition.
    public int getNumMeasures() {
        return listOfMeasure.size();
    }

    // EFFECTS: returns the total number of beats in the composition.
    public int getNumBeats() {
        int numBeats = 0;
        for (Measure measure : listOfMeasure) {
            numBeats = numBeats + measure.getBeatNumber();
        }
        return numBeats;
    }

    // EFFECTS: returns the total number of ticks in the composition.
    public int getNumTicks() {
        int numTicks = 0;
        for (Measure measure : listOfMeasure) {
            numTicks += measure.getNumTicks();
        }
        return numTicks;
    }

    // EFFECTS: returns the measure at pos
    public Measure getMeasure(int pos) {
        return listOfMeasure.get(pos - 1);
    }
/*
    public int getPosOfMeasure(Measure measure) {
        return 0;
    }
*/

    // EFFECTS: return formatted content of composition
    public String getContents() {
        String tempString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfMeasure.size(); i++) {
            int n = i + 1;
            tempString = tempString + "\n" + "Measure" + n + "\n" + listOfMeasure.get(i).getContents();
        }
        return tempString;
    }

    // REQUIRES: measure not null
    // MODIFIES: this
    // EFFECTS: add measure to end of composition
    public void addMeasure(Measure measure) {
        measure.assignToComposition(this);
        listOfMeasure.add(measure);
        measure.setMeasureNumber(listOfMeasure.size());
    }

    public int getBeatNum() {
        return beatNum;
    }

    public int getBeatType() {
        return beatType;
    }

    public List<Measure> getListOfMeasure() {
        return listOfMeasure;
    }


}
```

Comment: Maybe you missed the text on the right side when asking: "_Your question must contain code that is already working correctly, and **the relevant code sections must be embedded in the question**._" Questions must [include the code to be reviewed](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653/120114). Links to code hosted on third-party sites are permissible, but the most relevant excerpts must be embedded in the question itself.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ noted and fixed.

Comment: This is a well asked question (now that it includes the code), but you may not get everything you want out of a code review. The Software Engineering site provides design reviews and that may give you more of what you are looking for, but make sure to read their [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/asking). first.